# What is the 'unknown expr' error in drRacket debugger?

Tags: debugging, racket

I'm working with drRacket in a class on programming languages. We're using a language called pl, and whenever I try to debug code I get an error. For example:

```
#lang pl

(: add : Number Number -> Number)
( define (add x y)
   (+ x y))

(test (add 1 1) => 2)
```

Runs fine, but when debugging gives the error:

> expr-syntax-object-iterator: unknown expr: (quote-syntax (:-internal add (Number Number -> Number)) #:local)

All code gives a similar error when attempting to debug, regardless of it will actually run or not, and I've successfully debugged the code on other computers. Help please!

Comment: What version of DrRacket are you using? Also, where did you get `pl.plt`? I have DrRacket version 6.1.1 and `pl.plt` from https://pl.barzilay.org/pl.plt, and there is no problem when debugging.

Comment: I was using drRacket version 6.3, I tried an earlier version and everything seems works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem appeared to be with the version of drRacket I was using (6.3), installing an older version fixed the problem

Comment: You should try to minimize this somewhat: try to (a) remove the `test` expression and leaving a plain expression (if it fails, then it's not the test macro); (b) switch the language to `typed/racket` (if it fails then it's not in my language); (c) switch to `typed/racket/no-check`; and finally (d) switch to `racket` and remove the type declaration.

Comment: If it works after (a) or (b) then it's my `test` macro or my language implementation (email me about it), after (c) or (d) then the problem is in typed racket and a bug should be filed there, or if it never works then it's a debugger problem.

Comment: Final note: I don't recommend using the debugger in my class, and I don't use it myself.  I only recommend using the coverage feature.